# error 404 yii2 usando gii

Tags: php, yii2

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en yii2, para cargar toda la información base o módulos de mantenimiento de la aplicación estoy utilizando gii para generar los CRUD.  Todo bien hasta que intento acceder a la carpeta de vistas creada para una tabla cuyo nombre es competencia_tipos.
La base de datos está en mysql.
En un primer intento cree el modelo (usando gii) con el nombre tal como está, generó el modelo Competencia_Tipos y la carpeta competencia_tipos con todas las vistas correspondientes, pero al intentar ir a http://localhost:8080/index.php?r=competencia_tipos me laza un error 404 (No encontrada) Lo eliminé y lo cree nuevamente.
En este segundo intento el modelo lo generé con el nombre CompetenciaTipos, carpeta en view: competenciatipos. Pero al intentar http://localhost:8080/index.php?r=competenciatipos  el mismo error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo idea de qué está mal, para las otras tablas, por ejemplo competencias, todo funciona OK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Leí todo lo que encontré sobre convenciones de yii para los nombres de tablas y no veo que represente un problema competencia_tipos, no entiendo qué está mal.
Agradezco sus aportes.

Carpetas del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo es el nombre del Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, la solución que a mi me funcionó fue cambiar el nombre de la carpetas de vistas de competenciastipos por competencias-tipo, no se del porqué de esto, pero fue lo que me funcionó. Tal vez por las convenciones de yii2...